# Sum over certains rows in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByB_Z7-ZBRvlb1FNd0R6V1ZWWjg/view?usp=sharing) and I want that if the column "Dia" there is a change in the month, then in the column "Suma mes" appears the sum over the numbers in column "Horas" that share the same month. As you can see, in cell E14 appears the sum of "Horas" in month August.

I can get the month from the column "Dia", but I dont know how to use this as a criterion in `SUMIF`. This is part of ifttt applet to track my work hours.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a custom date format and format column A like this:

dddd", "d" "mmmm","yy

Then to sum August use (column D last August entry) :

```
=arrayformula(sumif(month(A:A),"=8",D:D))
```

Here is a share if my test spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZWg9pXVPpBqh1-BykTEnoreZGoAKn-YZmNq3bfYz30k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If your cell is text and not a date use "*August*"  for the criterion:  `sumif(A3:A, "*August*", D3:D)` as this will match August in any part of the string.  If it is a formatted as a Date use the formula in this answer, which should work with any date format applied to column A.  If formatting is set to Automatic, then it should become a Date and the answer above is still valid.

Comment: Thank you!!! Finally I have made this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(D:D,MONTH(A:A),MONTH(A14),YEAR(A:A),YEAR(A14)))` to sum over cell with same month and year